# Power Outage Killed Wireless Mouse

Tags: wireless

Why did my wireless mouse quit working after a three day power outage following severe thunderstorm/tornado event? How can I recover wireless usage?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which OS and version are you using? Does this mouse use a rechargeable battery, and it's it changed? Have you tried unplugging and replugging the dongle? Does it use WiFi or Bluetooth? Add these information [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1488617/edit).